# How can I dockerize a microservices project that uses a shared library?

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to create a simple microservices-based application with services written in Python 3.8. To avoid code duplication, I am using a shared library `common`.

A simplified version of the folder structure of the project looks like this:

- common/

  - src/
  - tests/
- service1/

  - src/
  - tests/
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- service2/

  - src/
  - tests/
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- service3/

  - src/
  - tests/
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- service4/

  - src/
  - tests/
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- docker-compose.yml
- requirements.txt

Each `Dockerfile` is similar:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app



# Copy the contents of the directory to the Docker image
COPY . .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose any necessary ports for the microservice to listen on
EXPOSE 8003

# Run the command to start the microservice
CMD [ "python", "./src/app.py" ]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  rabbitmq3:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    image: rabbitmq:3.11.15-management-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'

  service1:
    build: ./service1
    volumes:
      - /common:/app/common
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  service2:
    build: ./service2
    volumes:
      - /common:/app/common
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'

  service3:
    build: ./service3
    volumes:
      - /common:/app/common
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8003:8003'

  service4:
    build: ./service4
    volumes:
      - /common:/app/common
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8004:8004'
```

However, when running `docker-compose build`, the source files which import functionality from the `common` package throw the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'`.

Is there a Docker pattern that I am missing, or is there even a better solution to do this?

Comment: You will need to modify Dockerfile for each project to copy common files also.